# Devexpress DockManager and tab captions

Tags: tabs, devexpress, docking, caption

I have a tab container, where i can add many tabs with long captions. The default behavior of devex panels is to shrink the caption of the tabs (e.g. MyLongtabName -> MyLong...). How can i disable this behavior (the caption of the tab pages should remain intact) and instead get a scroll-bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to set the TabsScroll property to true on the parent container